Sheetrock thickness for basement with studs 24 inches apart
I am pretty new the home ownership realm and will be finishing our basement. We will have a contractor hang the sheetrock but I am trying to decide if I should go with standard 1/2 sheetrock or go to 5/8ths due to the basement being framed out with 24 inch stud spacing on all non-loadbearing walls. The thought is that the thicker sheetrock may add some strength and decrease the risk of damage to the sheetrock from my rambunctious kids. My only concern with the thicker sheetrock is it may be more difficult to get the right size door jambs, outlet boxes, etc. I would appreciate some advice from people who know what they are talking about.

Use the 1/2" and don't create problems, as you have eluded, with doorframes and such.  1/2" is surprisingly stronger than thought, and repairs will be easy as compared to the issues you can face when dealing with the thicker walls.  You could also make a "bonding experience" out of the repair. Making the kids take part in it.  ( That alone may be the impetus for them to be more careful.)
